# What is Wrong with Code Formatting

Tags: bug, code-formatting

All, I have noticed that all the code formatting for questions or answers new or old is 'flat'. That is all indentation of the code is gone even when the code has the required four-spaces allocated at each level. Is there maintenance going on, or is this a local problem (i.e. just me)? If it is a problem others are experiencing, when will this be fixed?

---

*Edit A. This is occurring with ALL posts for me. I have not changed any browser options (Although with Explorer it may have decided to change itself!). Here is an example of some C# code, that* is *correctly formatted with spaces* not *some other special characters:*

[image]

*Edit B. To address the fact that this is a 'Killercam not formatting properly error' I attach a screenshot of one of @Makoto's answers with the formatting "busted"!*

[image]

Comment: Most likely you are not using normal spaces, but other unicode characters that *appear* to be spaces.  Do you have an example?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: It happened to me to, and in all the case the browser on the Mac inserted strange characters that seemed white spaces.

Comment: I understand this could be a browser issue, but I have not changed any options what-so-ever. This started happening for all code blocks on the site yesterday evening...

Comment: I don't really notice an issue elsewhere...are you certain that this particular post was "properly" formatted before?

Comment: Can you post an answer with a code block in the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), and then provide a link?

Comment: @Makoto I have edited the question to show one of your answers with the same code formatting problems!

Comment: @DavidRobinson I don't have enough rep (10 points) to answer it...

Comment: @killercam: how about now?

Comment: @DavidRobinson http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174006/164125

Comment: @Killercam: It looks like it's formatted fine to me...

Comment: Okay cheers, it must be my browser, but god knows how to fix it...

Comment: Well...on my box it looks fine.  Include which browser and version in this report.

Comment: This is Microsoft's IE10. Version 10.0.9200.16521.

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this turned out to be an Internet Explorer issue. The version number of the current build of IE10 is Version 10.0.9200.16521.

Now for the fix. Somehow, compatibility view (not shown in the search bar by default was switched off). This needs to be switched on to correctly format the code which is displayed on the StackExchange sites. To do this <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>F12 Developer Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Browser Mode</kbd> switch this to 'IE10 Compact View'. Done.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running exactly the same version of IE10 as you, and I don't see an issue with directly typed or code pasted from Visual Studio. I'm *not* using compatibility mode. That said, I had a commercial WYSIWYG editor blow up after upgrading to IE10, so it's very possible that IE is related to your issue.